# Can I edit model variables with OpenModelica's GUI?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Is it possible to add and edit variables of a class in OpenModelica's GUI, or do I need to do it in the textual editor?

Dymola and other tools have such features, but I haven't been able to find it in OpenModelica. Maybe I'm not looking the right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, such a feature has not yet been implemented in OMEdit. So you will need to continue using the text editor for this.

Answer (score 0):

In the OpenModelica github, [this open issue](https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/8066) mentions the same problem. The issue is part of the roadmap, so maybe we can expect this functionality in a future release.